# Putting text into a DIV element using ID's and JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been looking all over for a way to do this but most methods seem overly long or complex. I have a button and an invisible `<div>`, on the press of a button I would like text to be written into the `<div>` using jquery.

Say this is my html including the `<div>` element:

```html
<button id="buttonid"></button>

<div id="invisible"></div>
```

My jquery would start something like this?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buttonid").click(function(){
           //WHAT COMES HERE? TO ADD TEXT TO #invisible ?
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
     $("#invisible").text("your text").show();
});
```

Notes:

- I've added `.show()`, assuming that the div starts off as being not visible
- Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` if you're planning to insert HTML markup instead of plain text.

Comment: Woah thanks been under my nose. You get the answer mark as your answer was more in depth. Kudos and thanks!

Comment: Also just wondering forgot to ask, Can I style the text through the #invisible id or ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `#invisible` to target your CSS rules, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/3dQJa/.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the newbiness. =)

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic You're very welcome. Good luck with your exploration of jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to change the text/html of the div, use `$.text()` or `$.html()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonid").on("click", function(){
       $("#invisible").html('Foo');
    });
});
```

Of course, it's still hidden at this point, but you could reveal it using any one of the revealing methods, such as `$.show()`, or `$.fadeIn()`, etc.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buttonid").on("click", function(){
    $("#invisible").html('Foo').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the exiting content of the div to change, use :

```
$("#invisible").append("your text");
```

otherwise

```
$("#invisible").text("your text");
//OR
$("#invisible").html("your text");
```

Comment: You're missing `#` in front of the id selector.